# Connect Sphinx server using SphinxQl with password

Tags: sphinx

Normally we have connect sphinx server using API 
         sobj->("ip","port", "SphinxAttribute",5000);

In sphinxQL :
  Any option is there to connect sphinx server using username and password. LIKE 
       $s->DbConn("ip",'uname','pwd','',$SPHINXQLCONIPPORT);

Please suggest:

Answer (score 2):

Just leave username/password blank. Any are accepted. Sphinx does not use password based security. (just like you dont need to specify a database either)

Answer (score 0):

> No there is no way to setup username password.
>   If concerned you can make your index names hard to guess. there is no SHOW TABLES.
>   But in general just use a firewall to lock access to specific ip addresses.